# Hodge decomposition of a compact kahler manifold.

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, hodge-theory

Let $ M $ be a compact kahler manifold.
Then, we have :
$$ H^k ( M , \mathbb{Z} ) \otimes_{ \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{C} = \bigoplus_{ p + q = k } H^{p,q} ( M ) $$
and :
$$ H^{p,q} ( M ) = \overline{ H^{q,p} ( M ) } $$
We know also that :
$$ \mathrm{Hom} ( H_k ( M , \mathbb{Z} ) , \mathbb{Z} ) \otimes_{ \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{C} \simeq H^k ( M , \mathbb{Z} ) \otimes_{ \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{C} $$

My question is to know if there exists a Hodge decomposition dual to the objet $ \mathrm{Hom} ( H_k ( M , \mathbb{Z} ) , \mathbb{Z} )  $ which we apply the tensorisation functor, $ \bullet \otimes_{ \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{C} $ in order to have :
$$  \mathrm{Hom} ( H_k ( M , \mathbb{Z} ) , \mathbb{Z} ) \otimes_{ \mathbb{Z} } \mathbb{C} = \bigoplus_{ p + q = k } \mathrm{Hom} ( H_{p,q} ( M ) , \mathbb{C} ) $$
and :
$$ H_{p,q} ( M )  = \overline{ H_{q,p} ( M )}  $$
and :
$$ \mathrm{Hom} ( H_{p,q} ( M ) , \mathbb{C} ) \simeq H^{p,q} ( M ) $$

Thanks in advance for your help.